# Complex type for describing object schema with plain object

Tags: typescript

Here's the type I come up with so far

```
type Schema<T extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {} ? Schema<T[K]> : JsType
}

type JsType = "boolean" | "string" | "function" | "number" | "symbol" | "undefined"
```

it doesn't work. Expected behaviour - `kind`, `amount` and `isHalfed` should be of type `JsType` (because they don't extend `{}` I assumed). Instead they act weirdly and `isHalfed` becomes `Schema<boolean>` but `kind` and `amount` become `string` and `number` respectively.

```
interface Cup {
    content: {       
        kind: string     
        amount: number   
    }                    
    isHalfed: boolean    
}

const cupSchema: Schema<Cup> = {
    content: {             
        kind: "string"   
        //Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        amount: "number" 
    }

    // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Schema<boolean>'.
    isHalfed: "boolean"    
}
```

Even if it would work - it would not be perfect. In ideal world property `kind` would have string literal type `"string"`, `amount` - `"number"` and `isHalfed` - `"boolean"` (all string literal types). This level of type precision is desired but not necessary.

My implementation seems to make typescript think that all shallow nested properties extend `{}`  - so they have type of `Schema`, but deeply nested properties straight up ignore this behaviour (despite being wrapped in `Schema` type)

Is there a way to fix this issue?
And if possible  - is there a way to make it work even better (like I described above) ?

Comment: Primitives like `string` and `number` also extend `{}`.  Perhaps you are looking for [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` type does not exclude primitives like `string` or `number`. The only values not assignable to the empty type `{}` are `null` and `undefined`.

It may be confusing, but in TypeScript, "object" types surrounded by curly braces (such as interfaces) do not automatically prohibit primitives. If a type can be indexed into like an object (e.g., `("hello").toUpperCase()` or `(123).toFixed(2)`), then it can be assignable to an object type.  Since `{}` does not have any required members, then everything except for `null` and `undefined` (which throw errors if you index into them) will be assignable to it.  See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) for more information.

---

It's possible you want to use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) instead, which was specifically introduced to match only non-primitive objects.  If I make that change, your code compiles:

```
type Schema<T extends {}> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Schema<T[K]> : JsType
}


const cupSchema: Schema<Cup> = {
  content: {
    kind: "string",
    amount: "number"
  },
  isHalfed: "boolean"
} // okay
```

Although, as you said, it's still not ideal, since it looks like

```
type SchemaCup = {
  content: {
    kind: JsType;
    amount: JsType;
  };
  isHalfed: JsType;
}
```

---

Perhaps the "ideal" version would look like this:

```
type Schema<T> =
  T extends boolean ? "boolean" :
  T extends string ? "string" :
  T extends Function ? "function" :
  T extends number ? "number" :
  T extends bigint ? "bigint" :
  T extends symbol ? "symbol" :
  T extends undefined ? "undefined" :
  {
    [K in keyof T]: Schema<T[K]>
  };
```

which uses a chain of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to pick out the exact [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type for each primitive, and then falls back to the recursive object traversal if it's not one of those primitive types.

Let's see what we get for `Schema<Cup>` now:

```
/* const cupSchema: {
     content: {
       kind: "string";
       amount: "number";
     };
     isHalfed: "boolean";
   } */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYHUMBcALAMQwA8kBvAKCSXwE8ZkBleQiMEAHgBUkIZfBGAATKFQC+APiQBeKrTpIA2gGkkGYEgDWEBgHsAZkl4BdAFyn1ZgUJHikBgEYArCPHxIA-EjYcuPhtZKwApKF4mCCVJaiVGZiRwyMSFACJnAwMAGwgQYDSkAB8kNKh8TGAsQpK0owBXYE8MAwLi0uB6sGcINBrSqAZunP60xtEIIy0IUTS4ui1hNCMEZABhephFZSR4VuFgfCsaHbodLVErcsqsJR3wA0ajpE7u3rukWJ2MKAAJEGyRhmVkyOTywBicShdD2wHKu02-k4ICsSMCGxgsgUJ2UsIOzxxO3OYisZQqWmqABoPnQHk9Sa8en0PpJqd8-gCgZdSqDcvk5nRYkpYfCjFljh88SICTTdBcwhEogBuWV0w4KlIQFU7STa5Q-f6A4FJRXMPWSeQImBokAq6hC0CQWCrJBrQj5LAzbb0KJ+djIvhYj78QQHRy88E+HlZPltCzBuxhiTXClRsk3QrxnYh+xiCTERrNVpphpNfAtOMJ0MOCSM3pput9JBZ5Q5pNIZzYRZpztYRaZqu5xyDYbZNMjzLZAfZxM1pDjSbTURphdTYAzafKQnKdSabR6Qwmcyo-2BXjBFl2haHXorRCuzbemH7aUS05yklIFNVVVgR7ql4uiZFkPgNTljQjfJIWhXZWnheBEVPFE-QCHgMSxJ9YJvADtzOeUBnJKo0jZU41WeNJGwFZRWVAjkjW5DIY3BKihToAB6AAqLD4MQ1C3yw-F+KJfD0wpNI9XuP96Q6IDenEmI9TA+jSUggoVQtDi2PtIA)